# Create relationship at for each cypher-neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher, relationship

I have a statement in my backend that fires a query.
This statement is checking the maximum slot number existing in my neo4j database and afterwards it creates 50 more slots with a for each.

```
MATCH (s:Slot)
WITH MAX(s.number) AS maxSlotNumber
WITH COALESCE(maxSlotNumber, 0) AS lastExistingSlotNumber
FOREACH (i in range(lastExistingSlotNumber+1, lastExistingSlotNumber+50) | CREATE (:Slot {number: i}))
```

What i need right now is that every of this 50 new created slots will get a relationship to a new node called box.
The principle behind this, is that every box contains 50 slots. And if 50 slots are full with something that i will fill in my backend and no other free slots are existing this query should create 50 new slots and 1 box.
I tried:

```
MATCH (s:Slot)
CREATE (b:Box{number:1})
WITH MAX(s.number) AS maxSlotNumber
WITH COALESCE(maxSlotNumber, 0) AS lastExistingSlotNumber
FOREACH (i in range(lastExistingSlotNumber+1, lastExistingSlotNumber+50) | CREATE (:Slot {number: i})-[:in_box]->(b))
```

but this statement is creating 100 new nodes and every node has a relationship to an own box.
[Diagram Link](http://scribd.com/document/438557768/Untitled-Diagram)

The needed result should look like this in the Diagram but of course with 50 slots , i just drew 3.

Second question would be.
How would you recommend the creation of the new box ? In the code above i am hardcoding number 1. But when box1 with its 50 slots are full there should be created a new box with number 2 and slots from 51 to 100.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first problem with your query is that you lose `b` when you define `maxSlotNumber`. This will fix it:

```
CREATE (b:Box{number:1})
WITH b
OPTIONAL MATCH (s:Slot)
WITH COALESCE(MAX(s.number), 0) AS lastExistingSlotNumber, b
FOREACH (i in range(lastExistingSlotNumber+1, lastExistingSlotNumber+50) | CREATE (:Slot {number: i})-[:IN_BOX]->(b))
```

As for the creation of the box node, you can do something like this:

```
OPTIONAL MATCH (b:Box) WITH COALESCE(MAX(b.number), 0)+1 as lastBoxNumber
CREATE (b:Box {number: lastBoxNumber})
WITH b
OPTIONAL MATCH (s:Slot)
WITH COALESCE(MAX(s.number), 0) AS lastExistingSlotNumber, b
FOREACH (i in range(lastExistingSlotNumber+1, lastExistingSlotNumber+50) | CREATE (:Slot {number: i})-[:IN_BOX]->(b))
```

By the way, if you don't like `FOREACH`, you can do this instead:

```
OPTIONAL MATCH (b:Box) WITH COALESCE(MAX(b.number), 0)+1 as lastBoxNumber
CREATE (b:Box {number: lastBoxNumber})
WITH b
OPTIONAL MATCH (s:Slot)
WITH COALESCE(MAX(s.number), 0) AS lastExistingSlotNumber, b
WITH range(lastExistingSlotNumber+1, lastExistingSlotNumber+50) as newNumbers, b
UNWIND newNumbers as newNumber
WITH newNumber, b
CREATE (:Slot {number: newNumber})-[:IN_BOX]->(b)
```

Comment: I will check your queries later on when I am on pc, is there any specific reason  I should prefer unwind instead of for each?